# Convert from IQueryble<T> to T

Tags: c#, .net, linq, converters, iqueryable

```
public DoctorClass GetById(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new EmrContext())
        {
            var query = from d in context.Doctors
                        join c in context.Users on d.Id equals c.Id
                        where d.Id==id
                        select new DoctorClass { Email = c.Email, FirstName = c.FirstName, LastName = c.LastName, Post = d.Post };
            return query;
        }
    }
```

Here is error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'Mvc.Models.DoctorClass'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What i need to do with "query" to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost certainly want to use [`Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.single.aspx) in this case:

```
return query.Single();
```

Or possibly [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.singleordefault.aspx):

```
return query.SingleOrDefault();
```

That's assuming there will definitely only be one such result, if any. (The difference between the two is what happens if there are *no* matching records. `SingleOrDefault` will return null; `Single` will throw an exception.

If there could be multiple matches legitimately, you should consider what you want to happen. You could use [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.first.aspx)/[`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.firstordefault.aspx), for example .

Comment: but if query doesnt contain elements? Single() fill return exception?

Comment: That's when SingleOrDefault can come in handy.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that Single() will actually select TOP 2 (assuming this is context is to a DB), which I always find a little irritating.  So I usually use FirstOrDefault(), even if there is only one record.

Comment: @scott.korin: The point is that `Single` will spot if you've said that you only expect a single result, but there's actually more than one. If that represents an error in your logic, wouldn't you want to know about it?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `IQueryable<DoctorClass>` where you need to return a `DoctorClass`:

You could use:

```
return query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Which would return the first item in `query`.